# Displaying Multiple Lists on a page in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have a page in my demo Ionic App where I need to display two category of  items. I have created two arrays with the items and am using `collection-repeat` to display the items. The list renders properly, I see a maxumum stack size exceeded error on the console. The error does not appear if I have a single collection-repeat on the page. I have created a PEN to demonstrate it. Can anyone help me with this ?

See the Pen Multiple Lists with Ionic by jagzviruz (@jagzviruz) on CodePen.

Comment: http://codepen.io/jagzviruz/pen/XbrXym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `collection-repeat` needs its own scroll container. Try putting each in its own `scroll-view` with a fixed height per [this discussion](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/collection-repeat-throwing-error-when-using-multiple-lists/21093).

Comment: Hey Thanks!!,  that did it. The ionic forums are one crazy place to look for information.